# How to map over array of multiple types in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

If I have a variable whose type is an array that can take multiple types…

```
type myData = (RedType | BlueType)[];
//`const data` is of type myData
```

And I am performing a manual check on the types with a conditional to do some logic on the variable data…

```
     {data.map((element, index) => {
        if (isRed(element)) {
          return <Red data={element} key={index} />;
        } else {
          return <Blue data={element} key={index} />;
        }
      })}
```

As you can see, I am mapping the array and I return one Component if it is a RedType and I return something else for the BlueType.

However, typescript doesn’t like this, it doesn’t know I am manually doing a conditional. So it errors:

```
type ‘RedType | BlueType’ is not assignable to type ‘RedType’.
```

And vise versa.

I will always have an array of multiple types, that I cannot change.

Comment: You're looking for https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions

Comment: Or type guards.

Comment: is there no way to do this without having to declare a `kind: "red"` within the Types?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want your `isRed()` function to be a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). That is, change its signature to be something like

```
declare function isRed(x: any): x is RedType;
```

and your code should start compiling with no error.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: "it doesn't make" ❓